# Error "ImportError: No module named request" starting Python 3 app in Bluemix

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, ibm-cloud

I am trying to start my Python 3 app in Bluemix and it keeps saying it's trying to start.

```
-----> Uploading droplet (32M)

0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
```

I am also getting this error in the logs about not being able to find request.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
2015-04-17T08:35:50.88-0400 [App/0]   ERR Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-04-17T08:35:50.88-0400 [App/0]   ERR   File "server.py", line 7, in <module>
2015-04-17T08:35:50.88-0400 [App/0]   ERR     from wordnik import *
2015-04-17T08:35:50.88-0400 [App/0]   ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wordnik/swagger.py", line 10, in <module>
2015-04-17T08:35:50.88-0400 [App/0]   ERR     import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
2015-04-17T08:35:50.88-0400 [App/0]   ERR ImportError: No module named request
2015-04-17T08:35:50.96-0400 [DEA]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by explicitly calling out the version of Python that I needed.  In the current buildpack, Bluemix uses Python 2.7.9.

To call out what version of Python to use I created a file called `runtime.txt` in the root directory of my app. The contents of `runtime.txt` are below:

```
python-3.4.1
```

Answer (score -1):

Another possible cause of similar startup errors for Python on Bluemix is missing dependencies in `requirements.txt`. Ryan Baxter spells it out in his blog post [Deploying A Python App To BlueMix](http://ryanjbaxter.com/2014/03/18/deploying-a-python-app-to-bluemix/).

For sake of completeness, he goes on to point out other gotchas leading to inscrutable errors, such as (1) the Python buildpack level being incompatible with Bluemix/Cloud Foundry and (2) the application failing to retrieve the port from the environment variable `VCAP_APP_PORT` for starting the HTTP server. The symptom of the latter is an app that works just fine locally, but crashes with the error `"failed to start accepting connections"` once it's deployed. Don't feel bad if you see this error and scratch your head for awhile; it's a mistake that nearly *everyone* makes on their first deploy.